# Which crowd control effects cancel Nunu's ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Nunu's ultimate get cancelled by *any* crowd control like slow, or only by hard CCs like a snare or stun?

Answer (score 8):

Nunu's Ulti gets canceled by any hard CC, like Knock ups, knock backs, silence, suppression, stun, charm, and polymorph. This is why Banshee's Veil is a popular item on this champ. Slows have no effect on his ultimate, as they do not interrupt anything.

Note that interrupting his ultimate doesn't fully cancel it. Part of the damage will still be dealt. This damage will be [between 12.5% and 87.5%](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2325425) of the full damage, depending on how long he was channeling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Nunu's ultimate can be canceled by stun, knock-up, suppression, silence, and knock-back effects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nunu ult get's canceled by any hard cc, but I want to add, that its damage isn't bigest factor in late game teamfights. It's slow and that enemies needs to use their stuns on you and not your carries.